# yesod-auth-account and requireAuth functions

Tags: haskell, yesod

Functions `requireAuth` and `requireAuthId` leads to the compilation error

```
Couldn't match type `Yesod.Auth.Account.Username'
                  with `KeyBackend
                          persistent-1.3.0.6:Database.Persist.Sql.Types.SqlBackend
                          (KeyEntity Yesod.Auth.Account.Username)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: requireAuth
```

I am using `yesod-auth-account-1.2.5` plugin. Here is the settings:

```
instance YesodAuth App where
    type AuthId App = Username
    loginDest _ = HomeR
    logoutDest _ = HomeR
    authPlugins _ = [ accountPlugin ]
    getAuthId = return . Just . credsIdent
    authHttpManager = httpManager -- error "No manager needed"
    onLogin = return ()
    maybeAuthId = lookupSession "_ID"
```

What can it be?

I replaced `Username` with `Key Username`:

```
Application is no smaller than the instance head
      in the type family application: PersistEntityBackend Username
    (Use -XUndecidableInstances to permit this)
```

With `{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}`

```
Couldn't match type `Key Username' with `Text'
    Expected type: Creds App -> HandlerT App IO (Maybe (AuthId App))
      Actual type: Creds App -> HandlerT App IO (Maybe Text)
    In the expression: return . Just . credsIdent
In an equation for `getAuthId':
        getAuthId = return . Just . credsIdent
```

and

```
Couldn't match type `Key Username' with `Text'
    Expected type: HandlerT App IO (Maybe (AuthId App))
      Actual type: HandlerT App IO (Maybe Text)
    In the return type of a call of `lookupSession'
    In the expression: lookupSession "_ID"
    In an equation for `maybeAuthId': maybeAuthId = lookupSession "_ID"
```

Some else replacements needed

Comment: I've never used yesod-auth-account, but it looks to me like you new to replace `type AuthId App = Username` with `type AuthId App = Key Username`.